# C++ non-member function

Tags: c++

```
template <typename Frame>
Video<Frame> operator<<(const Video<Frame>& video,const Frame& newFrame){
    Video<Frame> v1(video);
    v1.append(newFrame);
    return v1;
}
```

Above is the code that is a non-member function which is going to append (function to add something to the list and the list is private) something to the video and return it. It is a-non member function of operator `<<`.

Below is `main.cpp`. I don't know why when I return and use `Utilities::printCharVideo(video);` to print the video it doesn't show anything. However, if I use this code inside the function, it does print out something. So the question is, why the video did not store the things that I appended to it, and how to fix it?

```
int main() {
    Video< Image<char> > video(5, 5, 1);

    video << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_2))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_0))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_1))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_2));

    Utilities::printCharVideo(video);
}
```

Comment: In the function you want to add `newFrame` to `video` don't you? Then that's what you should do. And return `video` *by reference*.

Comment: You probably want `template <typename Frame>
Video<Frame>& operator<<(Video<Frame>& video,const Frame& newFrame){
    video.append(newFrame);
    return video;
}`

Comment: oh , it work thank you

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. I recommend [this operator overload reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), especially [the canonical implementations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) which tells you how to overload [the stream insertion and extraction operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion).

Comment: i just know ostream is used to cost something only. but i already had a function to print out

Comment: You miss the point, which is that the *destination* of the "insertion" operator `<<` can not be constant. That's what you're supposed to insert *into*. It doesn't matter if it's a `std::ostream` or a `Video<Frame>`.

Comment: what? you mean operator << can t insert constant things?

Comment: The left-hand-side of the `<<` operator is the *destination*, it's what's being inserted into. So no it can't be constant. Think of it as an arrow pointing to the direction data flows.

Comment: At first glace, it looks like you are copying the entire video each time you want to add a frame.

Comment: ok thank you for help

Comment: You function does NOT append to the existing frame, but creates a copy, with added information.  Your code does not retrieve the copy, since that would need an actual assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You function does NOT append to the existing frame, but creates a copy, with added information. Your code does not retrieve the copy, since that would need an actual assignment

This would work, but would be really inefficient:

```
int main() {
    // note how your operator<< accepts a temporary rvalue as its first
    // argument... This points to something not being right.

    Video<Image<char>> video = Video<Image<char>>(5, 5, 1) 
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_2))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_0))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_1))
          << (Image<char>(5, 5, Utilities::PIXELS_2));

    Utilities::printCharVideo(video);
}
```

Usually, operator << (when used as a streaming operator) is defined as:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T& operator << (T& t, const U& u)
{
    //... some code that append u to t, 
    //    like t += u, or similar operation
    //    that actually augments t.
    return t;
}
```

Note that the return value is a reference to the first parameter, which value is modified by the operation.  This is **required** in order to permit 'daisy-chaining' operator <<() properly.